# AWS Amplify Auth GraphQL Local User Groups

Tags: graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am working on a project using AWS Amplify with a GraphQL API. I created a user group called admin and updated the model to allow access from admins - like so:

```
type Todo @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }, { allow: groups, groups: ["dev", "admin"] }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}
```

I have pushed the changes, seen that they are reflected in Cognito, and I have added the test@dev.com user to the group; however, when trying to mock this group in the GraphQL interface I am still unable to access records generated by other users.

[image: Auth Configuration]

```
{
  "data": {
    "getTodo": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unauthorized",
      "errorType": "Unauthorized",
      "data": {},
      "errorInfo": {},
      "path": [
        "getTodo"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": "GraphQL request"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I think I have a misunderstanding on how auth is working through this GraphQL interface/ AWS Cognito, but the documentation shows adding the group should allow for proper authentication. My understanding is that I should not even need to define the user here - simply having one of the groups should allow the query to work - as the model definition allows access for the groups `dev` and `admin`.